# URL images after migrating website to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, url, migration

I want to implement my static website to wordpress just for practice and learning this stuff.

My images not loading because my original url is like: src="/images/logo.png" and now in my local wordpress url looks like: http://localhost/images/logo.png but should be: http://localhost/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/logo.png

Have you any idea for this case? I can do it with find and replace in sublime but I'm wonder it there is a better way to fix it.

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple find and replace in your text editor is probably the simplest solution in this case. If your images were added in the CMS itself then you could use SQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WordPress plugin like this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/